# New glass bed, should I glue it?

Tags: creality-ender-3, glass-bed

I have an Ender 3, I got a new glass bed, the bed comes with glue on the back.

Should I stick the glass bed to the aluminium base? or just use it with the clips?
I saw other people just use the clips, but my glass seems to have a sticky back...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pro and cons for leaving the sticky protection baking paper on the slate of glass:

pros (for not glueing it):

- Can be removed more easily in the future (the [collant is not easy to remove](/a/7964), requires a solvent and elbow grease)
- Can remove the slate of glass to put it in the refrigerator to loosen stuck prints

cons:

- Need for binder clips that may cause nozzle collision and decreases bed size (unless you use kapton tape to fix the bed)
- Backing paper adds another layer of insulation (unless you remove it and all the goo)

Comment: Re: layer of insulation? Couldn't you fix without permanently gluing the bed & ruining it, by removing the paper then using mineral spirits/goo-gone/whatever to get rid of the adhesive and get a clean surface?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Updated to reflect removal of glue and backing paper, good suggestion. Didn't think of that option!

Comment: Once a such big area is glued, removal is extremely difficult/near impossible without warping the aluminium or breaking the class. I would not use glue at all.

Comment: I have a glass bed (did not come with adhesive) and instead of clips, I use Kapton (or equivalent) heat proof tape around the edges.

Comment: @DoxyLover One of my printers I do the same! The kapton tape also works fine preventing the bed to slip.

Comment: There are other types of clips that can be used to mount glass without creating obstructions for the nozzle.

Answer (score 2):

Use Clips on either the left or the right. The aluminum might not be flat. Using clips or the adhesive will cause the glass to warp, defeating the point of using the glass.